# seleccionar todos los th de una row seleccionada

Tags: javascript, html

en esta oportunidad busco conseguir lo siguiente; tengo una fila seleccionada al hacer click en su primer elemento `th` al cual le di una clase y con el `querySelectorAll` y `map` formulo un evento para cada uno de ellos, ahora bien, como consigo seleccionar los `th` de esa fila seleccionada, es decir solo los `th` que quedan en morado al hacer `click` en el primer `th` de cada row.

```js
let getSelectorA = s => document.querySelectorAll(s);

Array.from(getSelectorA('.ev')).map((e,i) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', event => {
    Array.from(getSelectorA('tr'))[i +1].classList.toggle('purple');
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 1rem;
}
.purple{
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>by</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Tras</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="ev">byOne</th>
            <th>dateOne</th>
            <th>trasOne</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ev">byTwo</th>
            <th>dateTwo</th>
            <th>trasTwo</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ev">bylast</th>
            <th>datelast</th>
            <th>traslast</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Al hacer lo mismo transformarlos `Array` no consigo como dividir los mismos y conseguir lo que deseo la verdad me pause en ese punto...

Comment: explicate mejor no te e entendido!

Comment: @Bryro necesito seleccionar los `th` que quedan en morado al activar el evento que he puesto... solo eso.

Comment: Necesitas seleccionar todos los de cada fila morada o alguno en particular de cada fila morada? Es decir, si necesitas [byOne, byTwo] o [{byOne, dateOne, trasOne}, {byTwo, dateTwo, trasTwo}]

Comment: Te referis a que solo la primer columna debería ser morada?

Comment: hola @Sema si exactamente eso necesito, todos los de la fila que quedan en morado al dispararse el evento, gracias!

Comment: Por qué usas th en el tbody en lugar de td?, los th son solo para encabezados, si usas th en lugar de td, te pondrá el texto en negritas y centrado automáticamente y tal vez no quieras eso. Por otro lado te recomiendo explicarte mejor en tu pregunta ya que no lo estas transmitiendo del todo bien. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```js
let getSelectorA = s => document.querySelectorAll(s);

Array.from(getSelectorA('.ev')).map((e,i) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', event => {
   var arr = Array.from(getSelectorA('tr'))[i +1];
   console.log(arr.querySelectorAll("th"));
    arr.classList.toggle('purple');

  });
});
// en caso de que solo deses colorear solo el th que se seleccione


/*el = getSelectorA("th");

for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++){
el[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   event.target.classList.toggle('purple');
}, false);
}*/
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 1rem;
}
.purple{
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>by</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Tras</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="ev">byOne</th>
            <th>dateOne</th>
            <th>trasOne</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ev">byTwo</th>
            <th>dateTwo</th>
            <th>trasTwo</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="ev">bylast</th>
            <th>datelast</th>
            <th>traslast</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: no entiendo realmente es exactamente lo mismo que tengo, donde seleccionas los th de la fila que se selecciona en morado al dispararse el evento?

Comment: con el event.target

Comment: pero el event.target me selecciona solo el th donde se dispara el evento, que en este caso es el primer th de la row... necesito seleccionar todos los th de la row donde se dispara el evento.

Comment: ya es que debes aprender a formular las preguntas bien!